# Query a closed workbook without opening it

Tags: excel, vba, macos, worksheet-function

I'm searching for a string within a column of a closed Excel workbook.

The following code gives a type mismatch error on MsgBox.

If I replace that line with `ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & Range("C3015").Address(True, True, -4150)` then the macro gives me a hard-coded value (in this case, the value at cell C3015).

How can I search for other values within columns of closed workbooks, without opening them?

```
 Dim wbName As String, wbPath As String, wsName As String

 wbPath = "Path\To\Workbook\"
 wbName = "NameOfWorkbook.xlsb"
 wsName = "NameOfWorkSheet"

 Dim ret As String    

 ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & Range("D:D").Find(What:="SearchColumnDForThisString")

 MsgBox ExecuteExcel4Macro(ret) // <--------- TYPE MISMATCH ERROR
```

Comment: Range.Find() returns a Range (not a string), Try Range.Find().Address.

Comment: Thanks, now I don't  get an error but the computation is incorrect. It keeps finding the wrong values

Comment: What does the Address() method do? Can I get rid of it?

Comment: You can't use that approach to search for a string in a closed workbook.  Why not open the workbook and use `Find()` directly?

Comment: Opening the workbook creates an annoying window, which interferes with the macro buttons. Is there a way to open, but hide (or don't actually display) a workbook?

Comment: Turn off ScreenUpdating, open the workbook, do the search, close the workbook, turn on ScreenUpdating.

Comment: [http://www.EXCELGAARD.dk/Lib/GetValue/](http://www.EXCELGAARD.dk/Lib/GetValue/) You don't have to re-invent the wheel :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your using the book in more than one macro you may want to leave the workbook open, you can do something like the following to open and hide it. You could also set the workbook to a public variable so that you can close it when your done.

```
Dim Wn as Window
Dim Wb as Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("your book")

For Each Wn in Wb
    Wn.Visible = False
Next Wn

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: This still opens the other project. Is there no way to query it closed?

Comment: I think the workbook will be opened (to some degree) to get your data, and every time you update the links. Is there a specific reason you do not want to have the file open?

Answer (score 0):

Other then using python, sql ado, or another language or cmd shell with python or simialar, there isnt a straightforward native way in vba to query a closed workbook (query a workbook while its closed). but i think we can open a workbook ***invisibly*** as you hinted at (*"Is there a way to open, but hide (or don't actually display) a workbook?"*) , instead so that you will not see it on the screen but the workbook would still open in the sense that Excel has access to all the data and VBA can manipulate it, **but it's very much  hidden from the user**.

```
Sub FindInClosedWorkbookpartmanyallXLSB()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim searchStr As String
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
Dim addresses As String

' Set the string you are searching for
searchStr = "S"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' Open the workbook invisibly
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\karma\Documents\workbook test to search.xlsb", ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)
wb.Windows(1).Visible = False

' Set the worksheet you want to search in
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' Search in column G ' i know you asked for D:D
Set rng = ws.Range("G:G")

' Use the Find method to search for the string
Set foundCell = rng.Find(What:=searchStr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    ' Save the address of the first found cell
    firstAddress = foundCell.Address

    Do
        ' Add the address to the addresses string
        addresses = addresses & foundCell.Address & vbCrLf

        ' Continue searching
        Set foundCell = rng.FindNext(after:=foundCell)
        
    ' Loop while we have not returned to the first found cell
    Loop While Not foundCell Is Nothing And foundCell.Address <> firstAddress

    ' Display a single message box with all addresses
    MsgBox "Found " & searchStr & " at: " & vbCrLf & addresses

Else
    MsgBox searchStr & " not found."
End If

' Close the workbook you were searching without saving
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

im my example im searching for any all strings, 'S', in column G by xlpart. but you can revert it to xlwhole and single result (by removing the loop) if you want.

if you want the results in sheet1 of the workbook where the macro is run, you could do this instead:

```
Dim wb thisWb As Workbook
Dim ws thisWs As Worksheet
```

before,

```
Set the workbook and worksheet where the macro resides
Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook
Set thisWs = thisWb.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

before,

```
  ' Loop while we have not returned to the first found cell
    Loop While Not foundCell Is Nothing And foundCell.Address <> firstAddress

Else
    thisWs.Cells(rowNumber, "I").Value = searchStr & " not found."
End If

' Close the workbook you were searching without saving
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

-------- 2
with python though it can be done alot easier:

**For Whole/Complete/Full Matches:**

```
## 
import pandas as pd
from pyxlsb import open_workbook as open_xlsb

# Set the string you are searching for
searchStr = 'S'

df = []

with open_xlsb(r'C:\Users\karma\Documents\workbook test to search.xlsb') as wb:
with wb.get_sheet(1) as sheet:  # Sheet index start at 1
    for row in sheet.rows():
        df.append([item.v for item in row])  # .v to fetch the value of the cell

df = pd.DataFrame(df[1:], columns=df[0])  # df[0] contains column names

results = df.isin([searchStr])

if results.any().any():   # .any().any() checks if there's any True in the entire DataFrame
print(f'Found "{searchStr}" at:')
series = results.unstack()  # this converts the DataFrame to a multi-index Series
for idx, value in series.items():
    if value:
        print(f'Row {idx[1]}, Column {idx[0]}')  # idx is a tuple with (column, row)
 else:
 print(f'"{searchStr}" not found.')
```

##### For partial matches anywhere in thw sheet workbook or part of a cell:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyxlsb import open_workbook as open_xlsb

# Set the string you are searching for
searchStr = 'S'

df = []

with open_xlsb(r'C:\Users\karma\Documents\workbook test to search.xlsb') as wb:
with wb.get_sheet(1) as sheet:  # Sheet index start at 1
    for row in sheet.rows():
        df.append([item.v for item in row])  # .v to fetch the value of the cell

df = pd.DataFrame(df[1:], columns=df[0])  # df[0] contains column names

mask = df.applymap(lambda x: searchStr in str(x))  # applymap works element-wise on a DataFrame

if mask.any().any():   # .any().any() checks if there's any True in the entire DataFrame
print(f'Found "{searchStr}" at:')
series = mask.unstack()  # this converts the DataFrame to a multi-index Series
for idx, value in series.items():
    if value:
        print(f'Row {idx[1]}, Column {idx[0]}')  # idx is a tuple with (column, row)
else:
 print(f'"{searchStr}" not found.')
```

as you can see what you asked for could be solved and done pretty natively and  seemlessly with Python . infact it is native to python.

but with and for VBA , best we could do is mimick not opening the file , and doing so "invisibly" in combo with what Tim Williams said .

**Something cool from/using cmd** (To look really cool you could query from CMD you could save a script like this and do all the calling from cmd).

```
import pandas as pd
from pyxlsb import open_workbook as open_xlsb
import argparse

# Create the parser and add arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--search", help="The string to search for", required=True)
parser.add_argument("--file", help="The path to the .xlsb file", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

# Extract arguments
searchStr = args.search
filePath = args.file

# Open the xlsb file
with open_xlsb(filePath) as wb:
for sheet_name in wb.sheets:  # iterate through each sheet
    df = []

    # Read the sheet into a DataFrame
    with wb.get_sheet(sheet_name) as sheet:
        for row in sheet.rows():
            df.append([item.v for item in row])

    df = pd.DataFrame(df[1:], columns=df[0])

    # Iterate over each column
    for column_name in df.columns:
        # Convert the column to string type and check if it contains the search string
        # Fill NA/NaN values with an empty string before converting to string
        column_as_str = df[column_name].fillna('').astype(str)

        # Check if it contains the search string
        mask = column_as_str.str.contains(searchStr)

        # If the string is found in the column
        if mask.any():
            print(f'Found "{searchStr}" in sheet "{sheet_name}" at:')

            # Get the row indices where the string is found
            row_indices = column_as_str[mask].index.values
            for row_idx in row_indices:
                print(f'Row {row_idx + 1}, Column "{column_name}"')

        else:
            print(f'"{searchStr}" not found in sheet "{sheet_name}", column "{column_name}"')
```

and type such a command in CMD:

C:\Windows\system32>**python C:\Users...path..\program_name.py --search "THE STRING YOUR SEARCHING FOR GOES HERE" --file "C:\Users..PATH..\YOUR FILE.xlsb"**