# Error 91 (Object Not Set) When Finding Data in Closed Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks, call them Book1 and Book2. Book1 is open, and I am trying to get data from Book2, which is closed, into Book1. Book1 contains a column listing a corresponding element in Book2. For example, Book1 has a column of numbers that correspond to another list of numbers in Book2. I am trying to use VBA to get data from a row in Book2 with the matching number to the one in Book1.

Right now, I have the following MWE that generates an Error 91 (Object Not Set) when I try to execute the code:

```
Dim path As String, book As String, sheet As String
Dim targetRng As Range, sourceRng As Range

path = Left(Cells(2, 1).Value, InStrRev(Cells(2, 1).Value, "\"))
book = Dir(Cells(2, 1).Value)
sheet = Cells(2, 2).Value
Set targetRng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set targetRng = targetRng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(targetRng.Rows.Count - 1) 'Ignore header row
For i = 1 To targetRng.Rows.Count
    Set sourceRng = "'" & path & "[" & book & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Range("A:A").Find(targetRng.Cells(i, 1).Value) 'Error is here
    targetRng.Cells(i, 2).Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'" & path & "[" & book & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Cells(sourceRng.Row, 2).Address)
    '
    'Do some other stuff
    '
Next i
```

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do exactly, but the ExecuteExcel4Macro function is not going to return a range, so you can't set `sourceRng` equal to the result of the macro.

Comment: Ah, that was simply a mistake when copying and pasting. I was basing my code on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069445/vba-excel-query-a-closed-workbook-without-opening-it

Comment: That is what is causing the error.  Have you corrected it and gotten a new error?

Comment: It's the same problem, but in another form.  `sourceRng` is declared as a range object, but is being set equal to a string.  This doesn't work.

Comment: While this most likely not the source of the problem I'd strongly recommend that you fully qualify your ranges / cells. It seems strange that the `targetRange` starts with "A2" (first "A1" but later offset be one row, so "A2") on the very same sheet that "A2" contains the source sheet name. Maybe you wish to reference two different sheets?

Comment: @OpiesDad, I realized I made a couple mistakes in interpreting the question I linked to, but both ways cause errors. It seems like I should be able to put it in ExecuteExcel4Macro and get a range object back, according to that question's comments.

Comment: @Ralph, I originally learned how to deal with having a header row by offsetting it. When I first tried it with Range("A2"), it still selected the entire workspace (because of currentregion?).
Either way, I know everything is working up until the indicated line.

Comment: It appears to me that you are trying to use Find on a closed workbook. This will not work.  I believe that you can get the desired results by query the external workbook with the ADO.

Comment: @Thomas Inzina, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I was reluctant to provide an answer using the ADO because it is a broad topic.  But I will provide you two examples of how you con query a Excel files using the ADO.

On the left we have the source file that we will be querying [Employees.xlsx].  On the right we workbook that we are updating [Sample.xlsm].  In my examples we are using [Sheet1] of booth workbooks.  Note that the ADO will use column headers as field names (id,first_name,last_name...etc.).

[image]

In Example1 we query [Employees.xlsx] loading all the records from [Employees.xlsx]![Sheet1] into the recordset `EmployeeData`.  Next we iterate over the id column of [Sample.xlsm]![Sheet1] and setting the filter of the recordset `EmployeeData.Filter = "id=" & Cells(x, 1)`.  Then copy the values of the records fields to the appropriate cell `.Cells(x, 2) = EmployeeData.Fields("first_name")`

```
Sub Example1()

    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long

    Const adOpenKeyset = 1
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Dim conn
    Dim EmployeeData

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=I:\stackoverflow\Employees.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    conn.Open

    On Error GoTo CloseConnection

    Set EmployeeData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    With EmployeeData
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Source = "Select * FROM [Sheet1$]"
        .Open
        On Error GoTo CloseRecordset

    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 2 To lastRow

            EmployeeData.Filter = "id=" & Cells(x, 1)
            If Not (EmployeeData.BOF And EmployeeData.EOF) Then
                .Cells(x, 2) = EmployeeData.Fields("first_name")
                .Cells(x, 3) = EmployeeData.Fields("last_name")
                .Cells(x, 4) = EmployeeData.Fields("email")
                .Cells(x, 5) = EmployeeData.Fields("gender")
                .Cells(x, 6) = EmployeeData.Fields("ip_address")
            End If

        Next
    End With
CloseRecordset:

    EmployeeData.Close
    Set EmployeeData = Nothing

CloseConnection:
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

In Example2 we Left Join [Sample.xlsm]![Sheet1] with [Employees.xlsx]![Sheet1]. In this way, we use CopyFromRecordset to update the data for us.
 `Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset EmployeeData`.

```
Sub Example2()

    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long

    Const adOpenKeyset = 1
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Dim conn
    Dim EmployeeData

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    conn.Open

    On Error GoTo CloseConnection

    Set EmployeeData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    With EmployeeData
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic

        .Source = "SELECT table1.id, table2.[first_name], table2.[last_name], table2.[email], table2.[gender], table2.[ip_address]  FROM ( [Sheet1$] table1 LEFT JOIN `I:\stackoverflow\Employees.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` table2 ON table2.[id]=table1.[id] )"
        .Open
        On Error GoTo CloseRecordset


    End With

    Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset EmployeeData

CloseRecordset:

    EmployeeData.Close
    Set EmployeeData = Nothing

CloseConnection:
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Note:** CopyFromRecordset will replace all the data in the effected columns. For this reason recommend using Example 1 until you become comfortable writing queries.