# Get Range from Closed Excel FIle

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to get data from a closed excel file, and so far, no solution posted has worked to do so without opening the source workbooks. I have tried using the ExecuteExcel4Macro command, but cannot use that since I need the search functionality of VLOOKUP. Using VLOOKUP, however, has its own problems. I can't simply do something like:

```
cell.Value = "=VLOOKUP(<search item>, '<filepath>[<sourcename.xlsx>]<worksheet>'!<range>, <col>, FALSE)"
```

because I need to do some processing of the source data before it is entered into the cell.

I've managed to get an MWE where it opens the source workbooks and runs

```
Application.VLookup(<search item>, <source range object>, <col>, FALSE)
```

which gets the data successfully, but I can't open the workbooks quietly in the background. One of the workbooks contains links, and a pop-up dialog appears, asking if I would like to update the links. I have attempted to suppress the dialog box with

```
Application.ScreenUpdate = FALSE
Application.EnableEvents = FALSE
Application.DisplayAlerts = FALSE
Workbooks.Open <source>
Set sourceRange = Workbooks(<sourcename>).Worksheets(<sheetname>).Range(<range>)
```

but I was not successful in suppressing the dialog.

VLOOKUP requires a range as the second argument, which must be a range. I have been opening the source files to get those ranges, but I am looking for a way to get those range objects without having to open the files, since it seems I can't open them quietly.

Comment: Have you tried the "UpdateLinks" parameter for the Workbooks.Open command, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Use the ADO when you need to get multiple values from a closed Excel file.  Here is an example where I use the ADO to get a specific range from a closed Excel file. `I:\stackoverflow\Employees.xlsx[Sheet1$A1:F21]`. 
  For a more detailed example check out my answer here: [Error 91 (Object Not Set) When Finding Data in Closed Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385053/error-91-object-not-set-when-finding-data-in-closed-workbook?noredirect=1#comment64216395_38385053)

```
Sub ADOGetRange()

    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long

    Const adOpenKeyset = 1
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Dim conn
    Dim EmployeeData

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=I:\stackoverflow\Employees.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    conn.Open

   ' On Error GoTo CloseConnection

    Set EmployeeData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    With EmployeeData
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Source = "Select * FROM [Sheet1$A1:F21]"
        .Open
   '     On Error GoTo CloseRecordset

    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 2 To lastRow

            EmployeeData.Filter = "id=" & Cells(x, 1)
            If Not (EmployeeData.BOF And EmployeeData.EOF) Then
                .Cells(x, 2) = EmployeeData.Fields("first_name")
                .Cells(x, 3) = EmployeeData.Fields("last_name")
                .Cells(x, 4) = EmployeeData.Fields("email")
                .Cells(x, 5) = EmployeeData.Fields("gender")
                .Cells(x, 6) = EmployeeData.Fields("ip_address")
            End If

        Next
    End With
CloseRecordset:

    EmployeeData.Close
    Set EmployeeData = Nothing

CloseConnection:
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a smart answer.

Comment: lol... I was happy to be able to recycle my answer from the other post.