# Store/Overwrite/Grab Data from Sheet Based on 2 Combobox values

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am creating a reporting tool in VBA which saves data in a worksheet, and then when two of the comboboxes are changed (Date and Team), the userform will populate itself from data in the sheet. Basically the goal is to have one userform which will both save the daily reports and also allow you to pull up older reports just by changing the date and team. This feature is so that team leads will be able to fill out the report ongoing throughout the shift and make changes as they go.

This is basically a two part problem, I need a macro on buttonclick which will search 2 columns, date and team, (think 4 different teams A B C D) and if no match of the two exists, then save it in the last row. If a combination of team and date exists, I want to populate other text boxes in the userform. [I will post a picture of the userform here for info.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACnMH.png)

Edit: Here is the code which is not working. The date is auto populated on userform initialize.

```
Private Sub cboL1Team_Change()
Dim i As Integer
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Line 1 Database")
finalrow = ws.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To FinalRow
    If Cells(i, 1) = cboL1Team.Value Then
        If Cells(i, 2) = cboL1Date.Value Then
            cboL1Product.Value = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
            cboL1Staffing.Value = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
            txtL1Pounds.Value = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
            txtL1Processing.Value = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
            txtL1Packaging.Value = ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What does your macro code look like so far?  It's very hard for us to help you overcome whatever difficulties you are having if you don't show us the existing code and tell us what bit is not working as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading and writing between userform controls and a worksheet, I like to have a single function that will toggle the read write based on a parameter.  Here I use an enumeration to make the parameter more readable.

I extracted the responsibility of finding or creating the new row into function `FindRow` which returns the range object of the target row.

When reading the data into the userform controls I use `With FindRow` and `.Columns()`.  `.Columns(3)` is analogous to using `.Cells(1, 3)`; I just think that it is a cleaner look.

When writing the data back to the worksheet I used `.Columns("E:F").Value = Array(cboL1Product.Value, ...etc.)`.  In practice I would have just reversed the read section and assigning the values 1 at a time.

### Standard Code Module

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum RecordEnum
    enReadRecord
    enWriteRecord
End Enum
```

### Userform

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cboL1Date_Change()
    If cboL1Team.ListIndex > -1 Then ReadWriteRecord enReadRecord
End Sub

Private Sub cboL1Team_Change()
    If cboL1Date.ListIndex > -1 Then ReadWriteRecord enReadRecord
End Sub

Private Sub btnSaveSubmitReport_Click()
    ReadWriteRecord enWriteRecord
End Sub

Sub ReadWriteRecord(ReadWrite As RecordEnum)
    With FindRow
        If ReadWrite = enReadRecord Then
            cboL1Product.Value = .Columns(3).Value
            cboL1Staffing.Value = .Columns(4).Value
            txtL1Pounds.Value = .Columns(5).Value
            txtL1Processing.Value = .Columns(6).Value
            txtL1Packaging.Value = .Columns(7).Value
        ElseIf ReadWrite = enWriteRecord Then
            .Columns("A:G").Value = Array(cboL1Team.Value, cboL1Date.Value, cboL1Product.Value, cboL1Staffing.Value, txtL1Pounds.Value, txtL1Processing.Value, txtL1Packaging.Value)
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function FindRow() As Range
    Dim c As Range, Target As Range
    With Worksheets("Line 1 Database")
        For Each c In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If c.Value = cboL1Team.Value And DateValue(c.Offset(0, 1).Value) = DateValue(cboL1Date.Value) Then
                Set Target = c
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If Target Is Nothing Then Set Target = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    End With
    Set FindRow = Target.EntireRow
End Function


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Range("Dates")
        cboL1Date.AddItem r.Text
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: 2 issues with this code. First it is writing a new line to the worksheet on cboL1Team_Change(), basically whenever I change the team, and when I do set cboL1Team and cboL1Date to a value which matches a record in the database, it is not populating Product, Staffing, Pounds, processing, and packaging boxes with anything. I think it because the write as already fired and so a duplicate record with empty values for these now exists?

Comment: when I try to run I am getting "User-defined type not defined" error on `Sub ReadWriteRecord(ReadWrite As RecordEnum)`

Comment: The enumeration needs to be in a standard module.

Comment: Here is my [Test Stub.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rd977pue9dq29mj/Read-Write-Userform.xlsm?dl=0) . If you can provide me a download link for your file, I'll hook it up for you.  Make sure that the enum is not private.

Comment: This worked perfectly after I made sure enum was not private. However, I have been asked to change this project to grab the same data and bring it into a userform (same style of userform) in a different, closed workbook. How would you alter the code for this? I would not need to write to the spreadsheet, only read it.

Comment: You would need to Query the workbook using an ADODB.Connection.  My answer to [Get Range from Closed Excel FIle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405868/get-range-from-closed-excel-file/38406489#38406489) will show you how.  You'll need to change the source query: `.Source = "SELECT * FROM [Line 1 Database$] WHERE [Team]='" & cboL1Team.Value & '" AND [Date]=#' & DateValue(cboL1Date.Value) & "#"`.  If you can't get it working post another question with the modified code.

Comment: Don't forget to update the file path in the ConnectionString.

Comment: Just posted a new question laying out some of the issues I am facing (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952543/fill-userform-with-data-from-closed-workbook-based-on-2-criteria)