# Fill Userform with data from closed workbook, based on 2 criteria

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I am having trouble using ADODB to search data in a closed workbook, narrow by team (think A, B, C, D) and Date and fill a userform in the active workbook with the data from the closed workbook. My first issue is with getting the connection string to work, the file I am trying to reach is in the same directory but ThisWorkbook.Path doesn't seem to be working. The data I am trying to pull is Team, Date, Product, Staffing, Processing Issues, and Packaging Issues. Also I am unsure how to use the data after I have selected it.  This is code taken from another answer which I am having trouble fitting to my needs.

```
Sub ADOGetRange()

Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long

Const adOpenKeyset = 1
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Dim conn
Dim EmployeeData

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Path) & "\Line 1 - EOS Database Rev A.xlsm[Line 1 Database$]";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
conn.Open

' On Error GoTo CloseConnection

Set L1EOSData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

With L1EOSData
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Source = "SELECT * FROM [Line 1 Database$] WHERE [Team]='" & cboL1Team.Value & "" And [Date] = "#" & DateValue(cboL1Date.Value) & "#"
    .Open
'     On Error GoTo CloseRecordset

End With

CloseRecordset:

L1EOSData.Close
Set L1EOSData = Nothing

CloseConnection:
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: just like this I think you'll need ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Line 1  no need for workbooks()  www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: Still getting an error when I take out the Workbooks() part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to adjust the field names accordingly.

```
Private Sub cboL1Date_Change()
'  If cboL1Team.ListIndex > -1 Then ReadWriteRecord enReadRecord
    If cboL1Team.ListIndex > -1 Then ADOGetRange
End Sub

Private Sub cboL1Team_Change()
'  If cboL1Date.ListIndex > -1 Then ReadWriteRecord enReadRecord
    If cboL1Date.ListIndex > -1 Then ADOGetRange
End Sub

Sub ADOGetRange()
    Const adOpenKeyset = 1
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Dim conn
    Dim L1EOSData

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Line 1 - EOS Database Rev A.xlsm;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    conn.Open

    ' On Error GoTo CloseConnection

    Set L1EOSData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    With L1EOSData
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Source = "SELECT * FROM [Line 1 Database$] WHERE [Team]='" & cboL1Team.Value & "' And [Date] = #" & DateValue(cboL1Date.Value) & "#"
        .Open
        '     On Error GoTo CloseRecordset


        If Not .BOF Or Not .EOF Then
            cboL1Product.Value = .Fields("Product").Value
            cboL1Staffing.Value = .Fields("Staffing").Value
            txtL1Pounds.Value = .Fields("Pounds").Value
            txtL1Processing.Value = .Fields("Processing").Value
            txtL1Packaging.Value = .Fields("Packaging").Value
        End If

    End With

CloseRecordset:

    L1EOSData.Close
    Set L1EOSData = Nothing

CloseConnection:
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: When you say adjust the field names accordingly what do you mean?

Comment: Nevermind, got it working. You are a genius man! Made my whole week.

Comment: If by genius you mean "You've been programming a lot longer and made a lot more mistakes than I have" then yes I am a genius...lol.  FYI: you are not limited to reading the workbook you can also use Update and Insert queries the ADO.  With a few modifications to the current code you can use the ADODB.Recordset that you created to Update and Insert the records. This reference should help: [Updating, Adding And Deleting Records In a Recordset](http://www.accessallinone.com/updating-adding-and-deleting-records-in-a-recordset/)