# Vlookup or another method to get info from closed excel document

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, excel-4.0

I have values from cells A1 to A20. I want to `Vlookup` each of them to get corresponding values from a closed Excel file. I found some ways that work, but I don't want to open any file even it stays hidden and don't want to write the `Vlookup` as a formula in any cell.

I tried `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` and `ExecuteExcel4Macro` methods.

1 - This is a working example: [ExecuteExcel4Macro to get value from closed workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259862/executeexcel4macro-to-get-value-from-closed-workbook), but I wasn't able to alter this to work with `Vlookup`.

```
wbPath = "c:\users\fatihmi\Desktop\"
wbName = "Ornek.xlsx"
wsName = "Sheet1"

MsgBox ExecuteExcel4Macro("VLOOKUP(" & "testString" & ";" & "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!$C:$E;3;FALSE)")
```

2 - I don't know how to reference or use a closed document with `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`.

```
Dim wk As Workbooks
Set wk = "c:\users\fatihmi\Desktop\Ornek.xlsx"
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wk.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim wr As Range
Set wr = ws.Range("C:E")
        
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("testString", wr, 3, False)
MsgBox result
```

There is a possibility to get range with `InputBox`, but I don't know how to use raw range data as in code with `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`.

```
Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter range", Type:=8)
```

Comment: You just cannot do that. You need to open the sourcefile. You could open the sourcefile, input the data inside of an array and then perform the vlookup. But you will always need to open it even if its briefly for a second.

Comment: "I don't want to open any file even it stays hidden" - why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405868/get-range-from-closed-excel-file

Comment: @Damian it's actually quite possible (if I understand the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a few mistakes with the `ExecuteExcel4Macro`. It should work when:

- You make sure to have double quotes around a string you search for.
- Use the proper parameter delimiter (`,` isntead of `;`)
- If you make use of the r1c1 notation

Some information about the above can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.executeexcel4macro)

You can check the output of the following:

```
Debug.print "VLOOKUP(" & """testString""" & "," & "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!r1c3:r20c5,3,FALSE)"
```

So the code should be:

```
wbPath = "c:\users\fatihmi\Desktop\"
wbName = "Ornek.xlsx"
wsName = "Sheet1"

MsgBox ExecuteExcel4Macro("VLOOKUP(" & """testString""" & "," & "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!r1c3:r20c5,3,FALSE)")
```

> ***Note***, refering to whole columns range can be tricky in r1c1 notation, so maybe you can suffice in changing the row to like 1000?

---

**Edit**

Might you have 1000's of rows, I'm sure using `INDEX` and `MATCH` combo will be faster. In that case the code might look a little longer but should be faster:

```
wbPath = "c:\users\fatihmi\Desktop\"
wbName = "Ornek.xlsx"
wsName = "Sheet1"

MsgBox ExecuteExcel4Macro("INDEX('" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!r1c5:r5000c5" & ",MATCH(" & """testString""" & ",'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!r1c3:r5000c3,0))")
```

Comment: Thank you for correct approach. I guess I can limit my work with 5000 row. Do you know how the ExecuteExcel4Macro method works, I mean in algorithmic?

Comment: @Oremdon, I'm not sure what you mean by that. Does my edited answer do what you meant?

Comment: Index and Match combo don't work right now but I can figure it out. Thank you. My earlier post was just a different question.